# How to use property of object... Python!

Tags: python, datetime

In a module I defined a class with the following `__init__` method:

```
class RMLoader(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.now=datetime.datetime.now()
```

then I'm importing that module in console:

```
>>> from video.remmedia.loader import RMLoader
>>> loader=RMLoader()
>>> loader.now
datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 4, 17, 40, 36, 523000)
```

the question is why it not gives me standard datetime object?

but when i do print it act like standard datetime object:

```
>>> print loader.now
2010-11-04 17:40:36.523000
```

But I steel cant use it in function where i need datetime object...

How can I use that attribute like standard datetime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a standard `datetime` object all the time. The difference is that `loader.now` will invoke `repr`, and `print loader.now` will invoke `str`. The first one is designed to give an accurate representation of the object, ideally one that would evaluate to an identical object. The second one is designed to provide a readable representation of the object.

There is documentation on this [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization).